# How do browsers “stream” compressed responses?

Tags: html, browser, compression

I have a large HTML file, which I serve compressed using gzip. I've noticed the browser starts to display content from the file before the HTTP response is complete. You can mimic this on the command line:

```
curl -v -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' --limit-rate 2K 'http://www.theguardian.com/uk' | gzip --decompress
```

I'm trying to understand how the browser can do this. My understanding of compression is the whole file is compressed, and you would need a complete response to decompress it, but that is obviously not correct.

How does the browser manage to decompress the response in "chunks"? Is this to do with the compression technique?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't need the complete response to decompress it.  deflate compressed data (the format used in gzip streams) is a sequence of coded literal bytes and length/distance pairs (matches to previously uncompressed data), where those codes start producing uncompressed data immediately upon receipt.

dynamic deflate blocks have about a 60 to 80 byte header describing the codes, so you only have to wait for the gzip header (10 bytes) and the first dynamic header to be able to start generating uncompressed data.  Fixed-code deflate blocks use a pre-defined set of codes, and so you start getting data from those in the first two bytes.